# SQL simple query incorrect output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
dept_emp{emp_no(pk), dept_no(pk)} 
departments{dept_no(pk), dept_name}
```

The question is: `Retrieve the emp_no of employees who had worked in the ‘Education’ department but had not worked in the "development" department.

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.emp_no 
FROM
   (SELECT m.emp_no
    FROM departments d, dept_emp m
    WHERE d.dept_no = m.dept_no AND d.dept_name='Education') t1,
   (SELECT m.emp_no
    FROM departments d, dept_emp m
    WHERE d.dept_no = m.dept_no AND d.dept_name='Development') t2
WHERE t1.emp_no != t2.emp_no;
```

The idea is: `First select all the employees who work for the Education Department. Second, select the employees who work for the Development department. Finally, select the ids that do not exist in the second table(e.g people who work at the Development department`

I am trying to achieve:
1. Select all the employees who work in the Education department.
2. Select all the employees who work in the Development department.
3. Perform a minus operation

Why this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting? Incompatible datatypes while performing `minus`, some syntax error or something else?

Comment: @YusufHassan I am just not getting the correct output. The statements execute without a problem. Moreover, I was concern about the logic of the query. Maybe I have to rewrite is differently?

Comment: `minus` will work fine. It always does for me. The alternative that you have is to check the existence by using  `not exists`. OR, you may use a join as well with `is null` condition. Keep `not in` as your last resort.

Comment: Your join condition is wrong.  You have 2 tables, one with employees that work in Education, another with employees that work in Development.  Your join `t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no` will join every row are not the same employee (ie employee1 to employee2, employee1 to employee3, employee2 to employee4, ...).

Comment: What you want is the SAME employees that work in Education and not in Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `not in`

```
  SELECT m.emp_no
  FROM departments d
  INNER JOIN  dept_emp m on  d.dept_no = m.dept_no 
        AND d.dept_name='Education'
  WHERE m.emp_no not in (
      SELECT m.emp_no
      FROM departments d
      INNER JOIN  dept_emp m on  d.dept_no = m.dept_no 
            AND d.dept_name='Development' )
```

Comment: Give me a minute, I would like to check this out. Btw is there anything wrong with the logic of my query. I am also concerned about where I made the mistake.

Comment: You have to be careful with a NOT IN. On a large dataset, it can get incredibly slow. The NOT EXISTS style is probably better. Or, you may also be able to use a LEFT JOIN.... WHERE x IS NULL style (usually very fast).

Answer (score 2):

Try the query below

```
SELECT de.*
FROM dept_emp de
JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept_no
WHERE d.dept_name = 'Education' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dept_emp i_de
    JOIN departments i_d ON i_d.dept_no = i_de.dept_no
    WHERE i_d.dept_name = 'Development' AND i_de.emp_no = de.emp_no
)
```

The outer query select employees that work in Education department.  The inner query select employees that work in Development department.

The `NOT EXISTS` will negate the inner query (ie employees that do not work in Development department).

The equality `i_de.emp_no = de.emp_no` makes sure comparison is done on the same employee.